React/Express - Express shows data when viewed from local host, but not from other PCs on the LAN
I have created a react app to pull data from mongoDB and display the live info in a table using react.  This all works nicely when using the dev and even serve -s build command and viewing this locally from the windows server using a browser, however when I go to another PC on the lan and browse to that servers IP followed by port I get the HTML part of the page, but no tables populate.
express.js:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const port = 3005;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://superuser:recacted@cisuperleague.oyilg9e.mongodb.net/league');

const driversSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    driver_name: String,
    current_pos: Number,
    qually_total: Number,
    total_race: Number,
    total_points: Number,
    headshot: String
});

const constructorsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    constructor_name: String,
    ot_gained: Number,
    race_points: Number,
    fastest_lap: Number,
    total_p: Number,
    car: String,
});

const predictionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    pole_pos: String,
    fast_lap: String,
    safety_cars: String,
    bonus: String,
    pole_pic: String,
    fl_pic: String,
});

const teamsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tname: String,
    tdriver1: String,
    tdriver2: String,
    tdriver3: String,
    tcon1: String,
    tcon2: String,
    tcon3: String,
    tpod1: String,
    tpod2: String,
    tpod3: String,
    tpodium: String,
    tpole: String,
    tfastest: String,
    tsc: String,
    tbonus: String,
    tstpoints: Number,
  });

const Driver = mongoose.model('Driver', driversSchema); 
const Constructor = mongoose.model('Constructor', constructorsSchema);
const Prediction = mongoose.model('Prediction', predictionsSchema);
const Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamsSchema);

app.get('/getDrivers', (req, res) => {
    Driver.find()
        .then(drivers => res.json(drivers))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
});

app.get('/getConstructors', (req, res) => {
    Constructor.find()
        .then(constructors => res.json(constructors))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
});

app.get('/getPredictions', (req, res) => {
    Prediction.find()
        .then(predictions => res.json(predictions))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
});

app.get('/getTeams', (req, res) => {
    Team.find()
        .then(teams => res.json(teams))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://0.0.0.0:${port}/`);
});

I can upload any other configs if needed.
Windows firewalls have been truned off as a test but still no joy.
